# Command line that opens SSMS not actually logging into database

Tags: sql-server, command-line, database-connection, ssms

I am trying to log in to a remote MS SQL Server 2012 by using SSMS and I'm opening SSMS via command line. When I run my command SSMS starts up and it opens my `.sql` file that I specify but it doesn't actually log in to my database. Here's the two versions of my command that I've run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe" 
     -S 172.18.211.76 -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -nosplash "full_path_to_my_.sql_file"
```

and

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
     "full_path_to_my_.sql_file" -S 172.18.211.76 -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -nosplash
```

Both commands start SSMS successfully and open my `.sql` file, but neither commands actually logs into my database for me. What I mean by that is that after I run my command the object explorer in SSMS looks like this:

[image]

so before I can do anything in my database I have to click on the connect icon and enter my credentials so the object explorer now looks like this:

[image]

In the past I was doing this and if I remember correctly I was able to use a command prompt to open SSMS and have it log into a database all at once but I can't find the command that I used to do it previously. If someone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here's the version of SSMS I'm using, just in case it's important:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  13.0.15600.2

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility?view=sql-server-2017) those switches do exist. have you tried using a more recent version of SSMS?

Comment: You are already logged in, take a look at the query.

Comment: In the command line type `ssms.exe /?`, you will see what is avaliable

Comment: @Sami I've done that. Larnu confirmed that the switches as I have specified are valid but the are not doing what they are supposed to, that is the reason why I am asking this question.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak The object explorer won't be as you need, it's the query which will be connected not the object explorer, there is no way to do this via cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this further I have 2 observations:

1. I didn't specify the name of the database I wanted to connect to in my command using 
   the `-d` switch.
2. I checked and either way, using the `-d` switch or without, even though the object 
   explorer doesn't show that I have an active connection I can still run the `.sql` file 
   that I specified to be loaded.

So, I guess the problem isn't necessarily that the command I listed doesn't connect to the database, the problem is that a connection is made but it isn't reflected in the object explorer. Thanks everyone.

EDIT: as @larnu pointed out I was running an older version of SSMS. I installed v17.9.1 and tried to run the command but got the same result, after the command is run a connection is made to the database but it is not reflected in the object explorer. Not having the connection display in the object explorer is minor seeing as the connection is actually made and statements can be run in SSMS successfully after SSMS has been opened by the command.